# Initializing an SDL rectangle in Racket and racket-sdl

Tags: lisp, sdl, racket

I'm learning Racket by writing an SDL application but I don't know how to initialize a rectangle structure. It's defined in racket-sdl as follows:

```
(define-cstruct _SDL_Rect
  ([x _int]
   [y _int]
   [w _int]
   [h _int]))
```

How do I create an instance of a rectangle? Specifically, I want to create a rectangle to pass into the following function as the last parameter:

```
(SDL_BlitSurface hello-world-surface #f screen-surface #f)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you are just starting out with Racket, I would recommend to use some of the packaged libraries for drawing, such as the [GUI library's canvas](http://docs.racket-lang.org/framework/Canvas.html) or the [OpenGL library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/sgl/index.html).

The [racket-sdl project](https://github.com/cosmez/racket-sdl), with only 3 commits (the last one being 2 years old), seems to me as no more than a feasibility test.

Still, your question is valid, so let's give you an answer. `(define-cstruct ...)` defines a C `struct` essentially as a pointer, so you have no obvious means to change its internals. You can create a small wrapper library in C with a function `make_SDL_Rect`, and use that, but it isn't worth the hassle. It would be better to define the `SDL_Rect` type using `make-cstruct-type`, which allows for the conversion of parameters.

See more info at [the FFI manual](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/C_Struct_Types.html).